# What language is Facebook’s Flux written in, and how does it get transpiled to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, facebook, ecmascript-6, babeljs, flowtype

Here is [Dispatcher.js](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/Dispatcher.js) inside the Flux repository. Despite filename extension it’s not JavaScript.

For example, it [uses](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/src/Dispatcher.js#L109) types:

```
class Dispatcher<TPayload> {
  _callbacks: {[key: DispatchToken]: (payload: TPayload) => void};
```

Can someone help me determine what language is it written in and where exactly does its ‘transpilation’ to JavaScript happen?

I see mentions of Babel in the [gulpfile](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/Gulpfile.js) and among package dependencies, but Babel seems to work with ES2015 by default, which isn’t the language of Dispatcher.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is written in ES6 (which is JavaScript).

The type system that you see is [Flow](http://flowtype.org). It's simply an addition to JavaScript, not really another language.

Babel can strip Flow types and transpile ES6 to JavaScript (which it will do by default).

Comment: Oh I see, thanks a lot. I guess if I saw an extra Babel transformer I might’ve been able to grasp what this is, but ``flow`` indeed appears to be among the default ones [by the docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/).

Comment: Yes, the `flow` transformer is currently enabled by default.